# How to select items which belong to one group but not another

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, subquery, relational-division

Sqlite3

How do I select animals which are only pets and not food?  POF is "pet or food" column.  An animal can belong to both groups.  This is a smaller version of the real problem.  I don't want to split this into more tables.

```
animal  pof
----------
fish    pet
fish    food
pig     food
cat     pet
dog     pet
horse   pet
mouse   pet
duck    pet
duck    food
cow     food
rabbit  pet
rabbit  food
gerbil  pet
worm    <null>
chicken food
```

I have the following, but it seems awkward:

```
SELECT * from 
(SELECT  NAME, POF, count(*) as cnt
 FROM    ANIMALS
 GROUP BY NAME) AS GC
 WHERE GC.cnt == 1 AND GC.POF == 'pet'
```

Yielding correctly:

```
NAME    POF cnt
---------------
cat     pet  1
dog     pet  1
gerbil  pet  1
horse   pet  1
mouse   pet  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT IN` to exclude all the animals that have `pof = 'food'`:

```
select *
from animals
where pof = 'pet'
and animal not in (select animal from animals where pof = 'food')
```

Or if you want only the column `animal` you can use `EXCEPT`:

```
select animal from animals where pof = 'pet'
except
select animal from animals where pof = 'food'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ace26d67ec04bd0e0c69d42b1ca3db11).

Answer (score 1):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select animal, count(*) cnt
from animals
group by animal
having min(pof) = max(pof) an min(pof) = 'pet'
```

If there are no duplicates, as shown in your data, the count is always `1`... and you can use `not exists` to produce the same result (depending on your  data, this might, or might not, be more efficient):

```
select animal
from animals a
where 
    pof = 'pet' 
    and not exists (select 1 from animals a1 where a1.animal = a.animal and a1.pof <> 'pet')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can use aggregation

```
select animal
from animals
group by animal
having avg(case when pof='pet' then 1 else 0 end)=1;
```